# Image of a view shown in chrome but not in firefox

Tags: css, firefox, drupal, view

I made ​​a table with View and I replaced the link with a picture [Views]. It looks perfectly in chrome [Chrome], as I wanted, but Firefox only shows the first two images [Firefox]. The strangest thing is that Firefox includes a class to the image that I have not included (redlining).

Any idea?

[Views]

> [image]

[Firefox]

> [image]

[Chrome]

> [image]

Answer (score 0):

The problem was Add Block plus and the names of images, I don't know why. I chaged twitter.png to tt.png and voilá :S